Cordova-plugin-mfp-push Android API 34 issue
We got an issue with Cordova-plugin-mfp-push after migrating to SDK 34 : the notification sent from the MobileFirst platform, but we got this message in the Logcat Android 14:
   Received from FCM: com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage@63f7a2c
 Received from FCM TITLE: null  
 Received from FCM BODY: null

Build.gradle(app)
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    if (cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinEnabled', 'false').toBoolean()) {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    }

    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5"
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.8.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.0.1"
    implementation 'com.pusher:push-notifications-android:1.9.0'
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

build.gradle(android)
buildscript {
    ext {
        agp_version = '7.3.0'
    }
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

